# Is there a good site I can use to convert a string into any encoding?

Tags: encoding, format-string, ctf, string

I am working on a ctf (capture the flag) challenge and I have a string that I believe is important, but I don't know what encoding it is in.  Is there a way I can decode the string in all of the larger encodings used? For example base64, rot13, html, url, ect..

Comment: While your edit removes the request for product recommendation, I still don't think this is really about security.

Comment: @Anders I've actually run into a need for something like this a fair amount while working professionally as a security researcher.  A lot of times when I'm looking at network traffic of malware there is an attempt to obfuscate data by encoding it so that it can't be found with typical traffic scanning.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/cyberchef.htm). It allows you to try out a lot of encodings, compression, etc and you can chain them together. Can run in the web or you can clone your own copy.

[image]

Comment: interesting site and I'm sure I can use it for other purposes, but I really need something that can auto detect the format, or at least convert it to all different encodings and allow me to look through them and find the right one.

Comment: @MikeSchem Have you considered a text editor? [Atom](https://atom.io) should be able to do it; I know Sublime can if you have a Sublime license.

Comment: yup, I have the full version of sublime, but I would need to switch between every encoding one by one.  I would prefer one that is able to display all of the encodings of what my input at once.  Plus, sublime only know about file type encodings, not things like base64, rot32, ect...

Comment: @MikeSchem - You **can't** auto detect encoding with 100% accuracy.  Get any string in one of the EBCDIC pages encoding and try figuring out which page it is encoded in.  Most likely more than one EBCDIC page will fit the string.

Comment: Might be a nice script to write to just take in a string and have the output for all possibilities, then you could visually inspect which ones make sense. However, you will find things like a ROT13, which is actually a different Cesar type cipher. There should be some clue to limit it in the CTF you are doing.

Comment: @EricG that is exactly what I'm looking for.  It bothers me because I know I've stumbled upon one before, but I can't find it again!